# SwiftUI change sheet background

Tags: swiftui

How can I change a modals sheet background? For instance, if I have:

```
  Button(action: showAdditionalOptions) {
      Image(systemName: "ellipsis")
        .font(.system(size: 20))
        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
    }
    .onTapGesture { showAdditionalOptions() }
    .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isShowingAdditionalOptions) {
      AdditionalActions()
        .background(Color.black.opacity(0.2))
    }
```

The effect I am trying to get to is a blur effect that when a sheet is presented, its background is blurred and partly transparent. However I can't change the sheet's background. I can only modify a sheet's content background. Is there a way to apply a background to the sheet itself?

Comment: It is not allowed for now. You can use instead custom full-screen cover with view only, which background you can change. The possible approach was provided [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61811749/12299030)

Answer (score 3):

From iOS 16.4 it is possible to use [.presentationBackground(_ style: S)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/lineargradient/presentationbackground(_:)) with colours and blurs (material types).

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isPresented = false
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            isPresented.toggle()
        }, label: {
            Label("Sheet", systemImage: "list.bullet.rectangle.portrait")
        })
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isPresented) {
            HStack {
                Text("Detail")
                Button(action: {
                    isPresented =  false
                }, label: {
                    Label("Dismiss", systemImage: "xmark.circle.fill")
                })
            }
            .background(.yellow)
            .presentationBackground(.clear)
        }

    }
}
```

To support previous versions without messy code you can backport this functionality like this. Its is possible to fully replicate `.presentationBackground(_ style: S)` signature invoking `UIVisualEffectView(effect:)` but for simplicity I'll provide color-only version.

```
struct PresentationBackgroundView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    var presentationBackgroundColor = Color.clear

    @MainActor
    private static var backgroundColor: UIColor?
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        
        class DummyView: UIView {
            var presentationBackgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            
            override func didMoveToSuperview() {
                super.didMoveToSuperview()
                superview?.superview?.backgroundColor = presentationBackgroundColor
            }
        }
        
        let presentationBackgroundUIColor = UIColor(presentationBackgroundColor)
        let dummyView = DummyView()
        dummyView.presentationBackgroundColor = presentationBackgroundUIColor
        
        Task {
            Self.backgroundColor = dummyView.superview?.superview?.backgroundColor
            dummyView.superview?.superview?.backgroundColor = presentationBackgroundUIColor
        }
        
        return dummyView
    }
    
    static func dismantleUIView(_ uiView: UIView, coordinator: ()) {
        uiView.superview?.superview?.backgroundColor = Self.backgroundColor
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) { /* likely there is need to update */}
}

extension View {
    func presentationBackground(_ color: Color = .clear) -> some View {
        self.background(PresentationBackgroundView(presentationBackgroundColor: color))
    }
}
```